# How to make a nested Schema in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

name:"salman,

protein:23,

carbs:23,

calorie:1221,

fats:12,

ingredients:{

salt:1 teaspoon,

......

}
I want  a schema like this how can I make a schema of this with nodejs mongoose
also how can i add data in this nested schema because am getting error

Comment: What error? send a more detail

Comment: main problem is how can i make a schema should I make a array for ingredient If you are can we have a chat??

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have to create the table schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Health Schema
const HealthSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    protein: {
        type: String,
    },
  carbs: {
    type: String,
  },
  calorie: {
    type: String,
  },
  fats: {
    type: String,
  },
  ingredients: {
    type: object,
    default: {
      salt: '',
      fibre: ''
    }
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model(
    'health',
    HealthSchema
);
```

Here ingredients objects have priorly set the keyname. So you have to just pass the value at the time of creation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna skip alot of things here.

In your schema do something like,

`ingredients:[String]`

when creating new data do something like

`const healtData= await new healtData({... the data here})`

the do something like this before calling save

`healthData.ingredients.push(ingredient)`

`healthData.save()`

Comment: sir can you please elaborate the creating data because sir in every dish there are new ingredients and they vary from dishes to dishes

Comment: Can you just attach a screenshot of how you currently doing it and we can take it from there? from what I can understand, you want to create a recipe collection right?

Comment: yes sir I am making recipe collection like I have a dish of tandoori chicken so I have to add how much carbs it has protein fat and all and also I want to add a ingredient field which contains the ingredient and this ingredient vary from dish to dish